# Capture video without displaying the actual video feed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video, camera

So I have an application that can currently capture video with the front facing iphone camera and then do some processing on the video feed real-time.  What I'm trying to do, however, is make this process run in the background and put other controls onscreen.  So for example, say I'd like to run the camera and process the image feed, but I want the user to see a black screen with some buttons on it.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Did you do something already ?

Comment: Yes, I'm already capturing and processing the video feed, I just want to know how to move it to the background and display something else while it's still running.

Comment: If the user cannot see the result of the video getting capture, how do the user know the camera is pointed in the right direction?

Comment: (I've edited my previous answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an exemple code from Apple's doc: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html
there is also the way to customize the camera interface.

Answer (score 16):

Just so we get terminology right, by "in the background", you mean running the camera capture while your application is in the foreground, but not displaying the actual video feed. This is possible, but I wanted to make clear that if you move your whole application into the background you will not have access to the camera then.

There are a few ways to do this, but the one that I've spent the most time with is grabbing frames of video (or photos) via AV Foundation. Using an AVCaptureDevice and AVCaptureSession, you can grab the frames of video and route them to an encoder for saving to disk or for processing using your own custom code. None of this requires the camera feed to be displayed onscreen, so you can put up whatever interface you like and do this video recording or photo capture without any onscreen indication.

I would caution that you should make it explicit to your users what you are doing, so that you do not run the risk of violating someone's privacy. Apple does not react kindly to those who do this (for good reason).

I encapsulate a lot of this within my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) video and photo processing framework, so you could look at the code for the GPUImageVideoCamera class there to see how I configure the capture inputs. I hand the video frames off to OpenGL ES for the application of filters and other processing operations, but you could ignore that portion of it if you just wanted to do your own encoding or processing.